# Getting Started with MMDrawerController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to get [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) to work, and I'm having trouble.

Here's is how much app is structured in my storyboard:

[image]

Here's how I'm attempting to initialize it from within my root view controller:

```
//LCViewController.m

#import "LCViewController.h"
#import "MMDrawerController.h"

@interface LCViewController ()
  @property (nonatomic,strong) MMDrawerController * drawerController;
@end

@implementation LCViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc]
                           initWithCenterViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"centerNav"]
                           leftDrawerViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menu"]
                           rightDrawerViewController:nil];
}

...

@end
```

When I build my app, all I see is my root view controller. Is there something else I'm supposed to do to implement the drawer functionality?

I created a demo project to show how I'm trying to set up my app. You can [download the Xcode workspace here](http://d.pr/f/wFh7). Thanks in advance for your help!

*I'm using Xcode 5 and iOS 7*

Comment: all you can see is your root view, but can you slide it to see your left view? does self.drawController.leftDrawerViewController print out anything or is it nil?

Comment: I'm seeing on the white root view controller, not the blue menu when I slide. There's no available interaction/sliding as far as I can tell. http://d.pr/i/QqBp

Comment: This:  `NSLog(@"%@",self.drawerController.leftDrawerViewController);` logs this: `<UIViewController: 0x8a4d6b0>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry I initially misunderstood your app structure. The MMDrawerController should be the root view controller of your application. You should move this code from viewDidLoad to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. Add an MMDrawerController property to your app delegate, init the drawer controller with your appropriate views, and set the drawer controller to the `rootViewController` on your UIWindow. Do this along with setting the gesture modes as I described below and the drawer should work.

To get the basic open/closing gestures, set this properties on your drawer controller:

```
self.drawerController.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureModeAll;
self.drawerController.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureModeAll;
```

These properties default to `MMOpenDrawerGestureModeNone` which is why you couldn't make anything slide. You can have a look at the MMOpenDrawerGestureMode and MMCloseDrawerGestureMode bitmasks to get finer grained settings if you desire.

You can also create UI controls that toggle the drawer by calling `toggleDrawerSide:
 animated:
 completion:`.

Comment: Hmm... I tried that and no luck. Shouldn't I see my navigation controller when my app loads? And then I should be able to slide that away to review my menu view controller? At present, I only see my plain white view controller (I'm referencing the image in my question).

Comment: Hmm... okay, that makes sense. I got that working. So is the only way to use MMDrawerController to set the rootController like that?

Comment: No, the MMDrawer can be created and pushed onto a navigation stack or put in a tab controller just like any other controller. That just what you have to do for your root controller to be contained in the sliding drawer. There is no way to set it up in storyboard if that's what you're asking

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how to instantiate the MMDrawerController from a controller and not from the AppDelegate?

Comment: @Llg It's a subclass of UIViewController so you can create it as you would any other view controller. It can be pushed onto a navigation controller or presented modally.